# How do I alias `as` to `askubuntu.com` in Chromium?

Tags: chromium

I keep typing `as` into chromium's address bar and hitting return, thinking it would take me to [`askubuntu.com`](http://askubuntu.com).

Is there a way for me to alias it to askubuntu.com, so I stop wasting time closing the tab, opening a new one and typing in `askubuntu.com` before hitting enter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively there is a [Bookmark Keyword extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jgmmhndnlacimnjmgplphnokhnlbhnmd), that provides a similar functionality.

After installing, add a bookmark to http://askubuntu.com with the title `[as] Ask Ubuntu`.

Now it is possible to use the keyword between the square brackets to invoke the bookmark in the address bar. The detailed process is documented on the extension's web page.

As an example, to invoke askubuntu.com you have to type:

`kw`<kbd>TAB</kbd>`as`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

(It requires 2 extra key presses, but I think it is a good tradeoff between maintenance and usability. And for an added bonus there are commands that can be appended to keywords to modify the opening process. Eg.: `as:t` will open the page on a new tab.)

Answer (score 8):

In Chromium, go to `chrome://settings/browser` (this is the same as Wrench icon -> Preferences) . In Search, click on "Manage Search Engines". Add a new search engine, with details as follows:

- Name: AskUbuntu (this doesn't really matter)
- Keyword: as
- URL: http://www.askubuntu.com

Comment: I think the URL would be better as  http://www.askubuntu.com/search?q=%s

Comment: That would not solve the problem. The requirement is that entering 'as' and pressing Enter should go to askubuntu.com . If the URL is http://www.askubuntu.com/search?q=%s , that does not happen, instead entering 'as' and pressing Enter does a Google search.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to take effect to the whole of your computer, you need to edit the `/etc/hosts` file alias for that:

`64.34.119.12    as        # askubuntu.com`

To edit the file, type in `gksu gedit /etc/hosts` in the terminal

Comment: And so where is this hosts file?

Comment: That IP takes you to stackoverflow. :P

Comment: @jonallard, the hosts file is in the etc folder of the file system. You need to tick Show Hidden Files in the File Manager (Nautilus) View Menu in order to see it. You need to open the file with the command gksudo gedit /etc/hosts in order to edit the hosts file.

Comment: That won't work, because your browser would then send a request for `Host as` instead of `Host askubuntu.com`. The web server is likely to not respond, send a 404, or (what happens here) return data for a different website hosted on the same machine.